# nginx redirect of port 8080 gives odd result

Tags: nginx

In my configuration I have the following:

```
server {
   listen         8080;
   server_name    example.com www.example.com;
   return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...
```

The problem is that a call to `http://example.com:8080` returns a redirect to `https://example.com:8080` rather then the expected `https://example.com/` (implicitly to port `443`)

How do I avoid having nginx use the wrong port?

A similar rule for port 80 works fine, probably as it doesn't pass on the default port 80 as part of the URI

**Update:** The problem in testing is in part due to the browsers caching redirects, meaning any subsequent test will yield the previous result.

I added the following instruction to `server`

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

However, testing in incognito/private mode, I get the correct redirect, however only the first time. The second time I try the same link, I get the bad redirect again. wget doesn't display this behaviour, and always get the right redirect, probably as it does not cache those.
However, this means there is still something not right about the redirect I'm attempting, as the browsers apparently decides to ignore them with non-default port numbers.

Comment: Final comment. The problem turned out to be initiated by a misconfiguration on my part, combined with the dangers of doing a 301 redirect. Use 302, as browsers and search engines for all intents and purpose will treat the above 301 redirect as irrevocable and literally permanent. That happened here. I had the redirect without `port_in_redirect off;` and that resulted in https redirects to the original port 8080, now my browsers will never accept that domain on that port again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you told it to. Try this

```
return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri/;
```

Comment: I assumed as much, so I'd love to figure out how to make it do what I want. :P
By the way, that additional slash makes no difference. I still get an error when trying to connect with port 8080

Comment: I'll accept your answer, despite it not really solving my problem,. But the problem was NOT on the side of nginx, and while your redirect has a trailing / I'll still need to show that this is solved.

Comment: If it's not an Nginx problem then I doubt anyone could've helped, Perhaps you could say what the problem was, if it could be applicable to others?

Comment: I updated my question, and added a note as a comment to it. There was a problem in the nginx configuration, as `port_in_redirect off;` (default on) was missing. But the one I was really struggling with was that my browsers had cached the 301, and therefore never contacted the server again when resolving the initial request, and just silently did the redirect internally.